# Update query inside the Batch update execution is taking long time

Tags: java, prepared-statement, spring-jdbc

```
System.out.println("multipleBatchUpdateCheckErroreValues.update starting time------"+ new DateTime());     
multipleBatchUpdateCheckError(
            vSql.toString(),  //sql query
            pPriceMap.toList(), //rows
            50, //batch size
            new ObjectPreparedStatementSetter() {
              public void setValues(Object row, PreparedStatement ps, int rowNo) throws SQLException {
                Price vPrice = (Price) row;
                prepareValues(vPrice, ps, UPDATE);
              }
            });
        }
System.out.println("multipleBatchUpdateCheckErroreValues.update ending time------"
            + new DateTime());
```

In the above code, Update is taking too much time to finish. How to optimize the below code execution time?

SQL Query is

```
UPDATE PRICE_T
   SET TO_TIME = ?,
       PRICE_EXCLUDING_TAX = ?,
       PRICE_INCLUDING_TAX = ?,
       REASON = ?,
       PRIORITY_TYPE = ?,
       TRANS_TIME = ?,
       DEL_TIME = ?,
       UPD_TIME = ?
 WHERE CLASS = ?
   and CLASS_TYPE = ?
   and COUNTRY_CODE = ?
   and ITEM_NO = ?
   and ITEM_TYPE = ?
   and CURRENCY_CODE = ?
   and PRICE_TYPE = ?
   and FROM_TIME = ?
```

> Total rows 10k, columns 14, time taking to process is 35 mins.

Comment: How do you know the time is taken in preparing the statement rather than executing it?

Comment: i used the **new Dateime()** before and after the method as above.

Comment: Hiw does that exclude the update execution time?

Comment: Yes agreed, it will include execution time also

Comment: So your title and question need rewording.

Comment: Hint: if you correct your question, it is more likely that someone will answer it.

Comment: Title and question corrected

Comment: Your WHERE clause contains many fields. My advice:

 1. Check all the fields used in the WHERE clause are properly indexed
 2. Check that they are really needed (for example, FROM_TIME seems weird)
 3. You may also need to rethink your data model if a price really depends on so much fields. You may want to introduce a technical ID

Comment: I see no correction, just a mistake, and continued misleading. The `PreparedStatementSetter` is executed inside the batch update, not the other way around. You need to forget about the `PreparedStatementSetter` unless you can produce some evidence about it: this is all about executing the update until shown otherwise. You need to show the EXPLAIN for the update, and the indexes, or preferably the whole table definition.

Comment: No indexes on the above table and also no primary key because it's a input table to my application so duplicates also allowed to insert.

Comment: That doesn't answer either of my questions, but it certainly explains the problem. No indexes => sequential searching, times 8 for 8 WHERE clauses. 'Because it's an input table' isn't any kind of a reason why it should have no indexes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After creating the indexes on all the 8 columns of where clause , the execution time decreased to 1 second.

Comment: That is almost certainly overkill. I suggest you seek some help with SQL table design.